# Blas GEMM launch failed: what does this error mean?

Tags: tensorflow, cublas

I am having problems executing a simple Tensorflow model that worked well yesterday. I suspect, the problem in its entirety relates to the error given

```
      Blas GEMM launch failed
```

In the console it says,

```
  tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_util.cc:343] CPU->GPU Memcpy failed
```

My impression is that this may relate to my CUDA installation based on this

[TensorFlow: Blas GEMM launch failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990046/tensorflow-blas-gemm-launch-failed)

however, I can't see how to run the simpleCUBLAS examples. I am completely new to CUDA.

I have 4 1080ti GPUs (Ubuntu 16.04, TensorFlow 1.3.0) and I have not identified any zombie processes taking up GPU memory. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It can mean you ran out of memory.  Try reducing batch size or making model smaller

Comment: Yaroslav. Many thanks. I don't think the code can be the issue. This model ran many many times without problems over the past few days. Also, I reduced the batch size to 1 and image size (it's a CNN). I think there is an issue with memory allocation for sure, but not due specifically to this model. I also have had "cuDNN cannot create handle error" (again suggesting a memory issue. Been stuck on this for 9 hours....

Comment: `cuDNN cannot create handle` can also be caused by out of memory on GPU

Comment: Exactly. I agree with you, but it doesn't explain why a simple model with less than 100k parameters that trained efficiently one day, suddenly throws a memory error. I agree that the problem is related to memory - I'm just uncertain that the model is the issue. I thought I had some zombie processes but I don't. Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 2):

So I found the answer after days of going mad. I first ran this

I did this:

```
 cd /usr/local/cuda/samples/7_CUDALibraries/simpleCUBLAS
 make
 ./simpleCUBLAS
```

to check my CUBLAS installation. It returned CUBLAS INITIALIZATION FAILED!!!

So next I did this (based on advice)

```
 sudo rm -f ~/.nv
```

And it worked. Hope this saves someone else. Seems easy when you see it.

The other thing that is worth mentioning is that this problem also threw this error occasionally:

```
    tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:385] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
    tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:352] could not destroy cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
    tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:605] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms)
```

This was cryptic - everybody suggested it was a memory issue and sure enough, my GPUs got hogged by python during the initiation of my TF model. But it was the CUBLAS error that led me to the solution.